# Yum repo priority vs package version

Tags: yum

Suppose yum knows about repo A with package p-12000.rpm and repo B with package p-12001.rpm; and that repo A has a higher priority (lower priority number) than repo B.

How will yum decide which package will be installed?

Comment: (I'm assuming you mean "cost" here.) As far as I'm aware version always wins by default. Cost is a tie-breaker between repositories offering the same version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Higher repo priority (lower priority number) wins over the package version number. By setting repository priorities, you're configuring yum to install packages from a specific repository even when another repository has a higher version number.

From `man dnf.conf`:

```
priority
       The  priority  value of this repository, default is 99. If there is more 
       than one candidate package for a particular operation, the one from a 
       repo with the lowest priority value is picked, possibly despite being 
       less convenient otherwise (e.g. by being a lower version).
```